# React Native - 'react-native-asset' is not recognized

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

i'm trying to add custom font in my react-nativ-project. i added to this code

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {}
    },
    assets: ['./assets/fonts/']
}
```

in to react-native.config.js and

```
npx react-native-asset
```

this hapening

```
'react-native-asset' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Do you already have the `react-native-asset` package installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First things first

Make sure your config is named `react-native.config.js` an that the fonts are inside `MY-PROJECTS/assets/fonts`

### Try to re-install react-native-cli

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
# restart terminal, open a new one afterwards
npx react-native-asset
```

### Try to link

Maybe running the following command will fix it if you are with an older react-native version:

```
npx react-native link
```

Comment: `error Unrecognized command "link".`

Comment: I updated the answer, check now.

Comment: npx react-native-asset dose not work for me,despite that I install react-native-cli globally again.still have the problem.I am using react-native 0.69+

Comment: Can you post the log? @RaminKhodaie

Comment: thank you for your response in advance.by the way i was not install it globally.after running the command 'npm i -g react-native-asset', the problem solved and i could link my fonts to project.

Answer (score 2):

make sure installing react-native-asset globally before all configuration.

after running the command `npm i -g react-native-asset`,in order to link your all fonts to your project, run the command `npx react-native-asset`.

Answer (score 1):

make sure installing react-native-asset globally before all configuration.

after running the command npm i -g react-native-asset,in order to link your all fonts to your project, run the command npx react-native-asset.